# TypeScript: why function can return value despite that its type doesn't allow for it?

Tags: typescript

Take a look on these examples:

```
type Bar = () => void;
let bar: Bar = () => true;   // ok

##################################

interface Baz {
  (): void;
}
let baz: Baz = () => true;   // ok

##################################

interface Foo {
  bar(): void
}
let foo: Foo = {
  bar: () => true            // ok
}
```

Why TS allows for returning any type (in aforementioned cases `boolean`) when function's return type is `void`?

Comment: Type system won't complain until you try to use that return value as a boolean. As long as you don't try to do something with the return value, it doesn't care. Consider for example the case of an event handler that returns something.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void` as a return value says the return value of the function cannot be used, not that it returns no value.

This makes it easy for callbacks that often use inline arrow functions that return the result of their one expression.

For example, this lack of error allows you to write this:

```
type Bar = () => void;
let bar: Bar = () => doSomeSideEffects()
```

It doesn't matter what `doSomeSideEffects` returns, because the return value *cannot* be used.

And type safety is ensured because it would be a type error to use the return value of that function.

[Some reading on this here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#return-types-of-callbacks)